How to account for the mass of solid propellant lost when measuring the thrust produced in Newtons?
I've had some confusion on how to calculate the mass-lost during the burning of solid-propellant  $\require{mhchem} \ce{(C_{12} H_{22} O_{11} + KNO_3)}$  throughout the time interval of the burning. In other words, how do I account for the mass lost while the motor is burning?
I have done some research into this and I just cant find anything that has a work-around that isn't out of reach of my measuring capabilities. I would really appreciate any kind of insight, and will definitely respond to any questions that would explain/clarify anything further. Hopefully I have provided enough information for this.

The simplest assumption is that mass loss is constant. You know how much the fuel weighs and how long it burns, you can simply divide. That's the assumption Tsiolkovsky's rocket equation uses. If you need more accuracy, it would be helpful to know what you need it for, since that might narrow down the approaches.

For a solid rocket motor, mass flow is a function of burn rate and burn area. Burn rate scales with pressure. It is more reasonable to assume that the pressure is constant than to assume the mass flow is constant. The mass flow will likely increase (or decrease) in proportion to the burn area as the grain is eroded.

Perhaps the author of this question could edit it to remove the references to experimentation to avoid closure.. I have edited the question to remove any reference to at-home rocketry. I have a conflicting interest though because I have just written an answer.

If that fuel is supposed to be sucrose, it's missing a carbon atom.

Yep its fixed now.

The mass flow rate of a solid rocket motor can be expressed with the following.
$$\dot{m}=\rho_p r_b A_b$$
Here $\rho_b$ is the propellant density, $r_b$ is the burn rate, and $A_b$ is the burn area.
The burn rate of a solid rocket motor scales with the chamber pressure ($p_c$) according to St. Robert's Law:
$$r_b = ap_c^n $$
The coefficients $a$ and $n$ are typically evaluated experimentally for a given propellant formulation by measuring burn rate of a sample in a pressure controlled test chamber. Some information on how to determine those coefficients is given in this answer.
If you know your burning rate and your initial grain geometry, you can also calculate the grain geometry as a function of time, as (ideally) the grain regresses along the surface normal at the burn rate (given as a length per unit time).
If you have burn rate and burn area as a function of time, you can compute the mass flow as a function of time with the first equation I listed.
You may say "can I know the chamber pressure without a measurement?"  And the answer is "yes, if you know your thrust and nozzle geometry and a rough idea of the combustion product composition".
You might take advantage of the thrust coefficient:
$$c_f = \frac{F}{p_c A_t}$$
You know your thrust time history, so you can determine a chamber pressure history by rearranging this equation: ($p_c = \frac{F}{c_f A_t}$.). Here $F$ is the thrust, and $A_t$ is the nozzle throat area.
The last missing piece is the thrust coefficient. This answer gives the precise formulation of the thrust coefficient, but it is only a function of the specific heat ratio of the combustion products and a few pressure ratios. If the nozzle is perfectly expanded (obviously questionable if the chamber pressure is changing) then the thrust coefficient is purely a function of specific heat ratio and nozzle geometry (giving chamber to exit pressure ratio). You would probably get a reasonable answer by assuming 1.2 for the specific heat ratio and guessing a chamber to ambient pressure ratio. You could then iterate based on the chamber pressure you compute by combing the $c_f$ you now have and your thrust data.  I attach, for convenience, this plot of $C_f$ vs expansion ratio from the answer referenced earlier in this paragraph.


Not sure how helpful any of this is to a high school science fair project, but it's a great answer.

This is some really interesting stuff, thankyou so much for the answer, and I will try to include some of this in my explanation if a quesiton about mass loss comes up during my presentations.
